# How to tell from the hardware if logic board is Core i5 or i7?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, cpu, logicboard, motherboard

I have a faulty logic board that I removed from a MacBook Pro, 13 inch, Late 2016; my problem is that I forgot to mark down if it was an i5 or i7 logic board before removing the part. The board has the model 820-00875-A. Is this enough to conclusively determine which CPU it has, and if not, is there any other way besides reinstalling it into another Macbook? Thank you!

EDIT: The board I am trying to identify came from a function keys (non-touchbar) Mac if that helps to narrow it down.

EDIT:  I removed the heatsink and on the CPU there are 2 sequences etched: J615C415SRJM and 02168, neither of which bring anything on Google.

Comment: @SteveChambers Yes, but searching that model number brings boards that are i5 and i7, so I think that model may not be enough. I couldn't find any official record of which CPU that model would refer to.

Comment: Remove the heatsink and get the CPU identifier.

Comment: @Allan I removed the heatsink and on the CPU there are 2 sequences etched:  J615C415SRJM   and   02168, neither of which bring anything on Google. Not very helpful.

Comment: It looks like you’re missing a few digits from that number. The last 5 should fit the pattern SR#JM and if I’m not mistaken the whole number should start with an F (not positive on that one). Either way, those identifiers should be 15 digits; yours is 12.

Answer (score 1):

Found it with the help of @danj on the iFixit forums:

On the back side of the board where the board maker has their QR code, you’ll find a laser etched entry of the boards clocking 2.0 or 2.4. The 2.0 GHz is the i5 and the 2.4 GHz is the i7.